# iOS 8, iPhone 6 Plus Multiple Box Shadows in CSS3 Pseudo Element Bug?

Tags: ios, css

Just discovered this earlier, in an attempt to use CSS3 to create a navigation toggle with 3 horizontal bars, like so:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
.toggle button:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 68%;
height: 4px;
background: #fff;
top: 8px;
left: 17%;
box-shadow: 
    0 10px 0 #fff, 
    0 20px 0 #fff;
}
```

Looks perfectly fine on computers, but on iOS the two bottom bars (generated by the `box-shadow` don't display at all. If I delete the second rule, I see two bars (so the property works in this instance). But it seems like iOS doesn't like having two box-shadows?

Does anyone have a workaround for this, other than completely re-approaching how I'm creating a navigation toggle (like using font-awesome or an image)?

Comment: Try creating a fiddle (or better yet, a code in your question) that replicates this problem. When I do very simple markup using your CSS, it works as expected on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'border-radius:1px'` to help you solve your issue.